# Correct preposition use: regional comparisons in/of health care utilisation

Tags: prepositions, british-english

Which would be correct preposition use:

> regional comparisons **in** health care utilisation

> regional comparisons **of** health care utilisation

Comment: Reword - comparing health care utilization across regions. *Utilization* is a sort of collective noun that doesn't easily fragment into comparable parts. And you would need to use *utilizations*, and that sounds off to me.

Comment: If you're comparing one region's utilization to another's, use *of*. If you're making comparisons within each region, use *in*.